# How to configure HttpClient authorization per call

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to interface with Dahua facial recognition devices and they require digest authentication. Since each device could potentially have a different credential, and I didn't find a way to configure the request credentials using `HttpClient`, I could end up with a single HttpClient per device (which will be hundreds to thousands of devices).

The naive approach would be to instantiate a different `HttpClient` per device, but since Microsoft states that a single `HttpClient` instance should be cached and reused for all http requests, I think that I may be missing something and that such simple "per-request" configuration of network credentials may have an easier way of doing.

Currently I've created a "provider" which caches `HttpClient` instances per network credential

```
public class HttpClientProvider
{
    static readonly Lazy<HttpClientProvider> instance = new(() => new HttpClientProvider());
    public static HttpClientProvider Instance => instance.Value;

    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpClient> ClientMap = new();

    public HttpClient Get(NetworkCredential credentials) =>
        ClientMap.GetOrAdd(credentials.UserName + credentials.Password, BuildClient(credentials));

    HttpClient BuildClient(NetworkCredential credentials) => new(new HttpClientHandler {
        Credentials = credentials
    });

}
```

Am I missing something or is it this hard to achieve such simple thing as to provide a different credential on a per-request basis with `HttpClient`?

(I did research stack overflow before asking and didn't find a direct answer for digest authentication).

Comment: I think you should use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

Comment: To expound a bit... You want to use `IHttpClientFactory` to create and configure an instance of `HttpClient` for each request. The simple guidance from MS is to use a persistent `HttpClient` instance. But when that isn't feasible, using `IHttpClientFactory` ensures that the things that actually need to be cached to prevent port exhaustion are handled properly.

Comment: @JackA. that's not what HttpClientFactory is for. You can't use a static HttpClient instance forever because the sockets it caches won't reflect DNS changes. HttpClientFactory is used to recycle the sockets or more specifically, the SocketClientHandlers. Specifying credentials per ULR is the job of CredentialCache

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for my usecase DNS changes are a non-issue because all devices are addressed by IP directly. I'll check `CredentialCache` and also read more about `IHttpClientFactory`, but it baffles me how hard it is to achieve such basic functionality.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If `CredentialCache` can cache by IP address ("host" address) then it is really the solution.

Comment: Calling `cache.Add(url,credential);` isn't hard. It's actually *easier* than what you were looking for. CredentialCache isn't new either, it exists since .NET Framework 1

Comment: The IP isn't the host address at all. That's why CredentialCache maps the URL, not the IP. That's not nitpicking, it's very common to configure multiple sites to run on the same IP and port using different HOST header mappings. DNS will resolve multiple host addresses to the same IP and the web server will  map different HOST values to different sites

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that, I setup my own sites on Azure and for sure they share tha same IP, but in my use case all devices will be accessed directly via IP addresses and not DNS names. Anyway, CredentialCache will work nicely.